# Control traffic with reCaptcha

Tags: recaptcha, cloudflare-turnstile

I've got a client that comes in, with all the confidence in the world, telling me to put a captcha on all pages to block bot/scam traffic.

As far as I know, reCaptcha only checks forms; He would need something like [Turnstile](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/turnstile/); It even talks about migrating from captcha, but I can't seem to find a way to do it with captcha.

So before I put my foot in my mouth, I just want to make sure, is there the same principle with reCaptcha?

I did a bunch of research and nothing seemed to fit.